# Create a JSAPIPtr in javascript side of firebreath

Tags: javascript, c++, firebreath

I have a requirement as follows:
 **I wanted to initialize a user-defined class inheriting from FB::JSAPIAuto  but I wanted to create it plugin independent..like**

**In JS**, earlier i used to do this::

```
plugin().CreateJSAPIObject("someParameter");
//in order to initialize the c++ object with a value..It was successfully compiling..
```

**What I want to do is to create a c++ object plugin independent**

So in JS>>

```
UserDefinedJSAPIClassPtr obj=new UserDefinedJSAPIClass();
obj->SetMember1="This is Member 1";
//not necessarily using new keyword
plugin().DoSomethingWithObject(obj);
```

I came to know of [boost::clipp library](http://clipp.sourceforge.net/index.html)..and other numerous frameworks but am finding difficulty...as everything is strongly tied to the root JSAPI.

**My doubt>>Is this possible?** 
My objective later on>>
P.S:: DoSomethingWithObject(FB::variant& object)  will get the members of the JSAPI object (set in the JS side) and process them

**EDIT after Taxilian's answer::**
what in the case of this,
 In JS side,

```
 function AnotherJavascriptfunction(member1)
        {
        member1='2';
        }
var UserClass=function(color,settings){}

var userObject=new UserClass('Red',AnotherJavascriptfunction);
 plugin().DoTheChanges(userObject);
```

In FB side,
 how do i access member1.?
which method should i Look for to get the member of settings

**Regards, 
Pratik**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not possible to create a JSAPIPtr from javascript, but you can create a normal javascript object and pass it into a JSAPI method; it'll be a FB::JSObjectPtr type and you can then call methods/properties on it using Invoke, GetProperty, SetProperty, etc.